# When submitting a web form, don't reset data fields

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

How can I submit a form to itself without clearing the data in the fields using HTML, javascript and PHP?

Comment: see:<br>[http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html](http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could take different approaches (e.g. cookies, jquery, etc...), however HTML + a line in PHP are more than enough in this case. Try this example code:

```
<form name="test" method="post">
Your Name: <input type="text" name="YourName" <?php if (isset($_POST['YourName'])) echo 'value="'.$_POST['YourName'].'"';?> >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the code above if something has been posted to the receiving page (that can be the same page, such as in your case), then the posted value is printed out in the corresponding field. You can use this approach for all the fields composing your form.
If you want, you can also use similarly the $_GET method in the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the traditional form submit, you need to save the parameters and rewrite the form input elements when you write the form the next time.  But a better way is to use AJAX -- then the field data is sent without a form submission, and the input elements retain their data. See this link: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp